# Symfony 2.7 set header from StreamedResponse's callback

Tags: php, symfony, stream, header, response

I have to set dynamically my Content-Type into the StreamedResponse's callback.

I wrote a code like this that it works fine on Symfony 2.3 but not on 2.7. The returned Content-Type is `text/html`.

```
function indexAction()
{
    $r = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse();
    $r->setCallback(function() use ( & $r)
    {
        // ...

        $r->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // ...
    });
    return $r;
}
```

I found this commit that it can be on but i don't really understand...
https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/commit/6a0838a26d54eff153b825e1550c1f6fa05a0941

It looks like we can now only set header outside the callback.

It works if i send headers with the native php function into the closure but it's dirty...

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

if someone has a clue...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be accurate, you can use hack with replacing headers up to version 2.7.19, it was merged in 2.7.20

As @MichaelSivolobov said in his answer, I also have never seen cases when you need it

I'm sure such commits are always made for enforce better application design. When I see such cases as in your example, it's a some kind of red flag to rethink code/data flow

Answer (score 2):

Streamed response made for purposes when you need long-polling connections. And so you have to know what content-type it will serve before you send any data.

When you return your Response object in action Symfony already sends headers and starts to **stream** output from callback function. In this moment it is not right to send another header.

*P.S. I have never seen case when you really need `StreamedResponse` and need to set Content-Type dynamically.*

Comment: Into the callback I have to call a WS via cURL that returns me some custom headers (eg. Content-Type and Content-Disposition) and streams me a file content that I have to re-stream... @nikita-u

Comment: * (eg. CUSTOM-Content-Type and CUSTOM-Content-Disposition)